# How do I change the form's controls background color?

Tags: c#, metroframework

So how do I change it? For example my form looks like this: [image]

But I want the controls to look like this: [image]

Comment: The style is solely controlled by the windows settings. If you want to have full control, please create custom buttons like in this answer / question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29024910/how-to-design-a-custom-close-minimize-and-maximize-button-in-windows-form-appli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a bug in the library.**  There is a workaround:

- Add a MetroStyleManager to your form by dragging it onto the form from the Toolbox in Visual Studio.
- The metroStyleManager1 icon gets displayed below the form as shown in the screenshot below, and can be clicked to bring up its properties.  Do this.
- Under the Owner property for the MetroStyleManager click the dropdown and select the form name, which is Form1 in the example below.
- Set the Style and Theme properties you want in the MetroStyleManager properties.  This overrides any setting on the form itself. It may be worth setting Style and Theme on the form to the same values as well so it shows the correct colors in the designer.
- Run the project, the buttons should have the correct colors.

[image]